# Spaces being added in select query on Sql database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Performing a select query on a varchar(400) field in the database, which holds domains stored for validating requests, from my code in ASP.net using:

```
var domain = (Domain)(from dom in cxt.Domains
             where dom.uidclient.Equals(client.uidclient)
             where SqlMethods.Like(properties[2], "%" + dom.url + "%") || properties[2].Equals(dom.url)
             select dom).First<Domain>();
```

Where 'properties[2]' is the domain I am trying to match in the database. However it returns no matching values, despite the entry being there.

But when I perform a select query on the entry I am trying to retrieve in SQL Server Management, it has an additional space added to the domain entry (e.g. 'http://[space]www.site.co.uk') but when I attempt to edit the entry, the space is no longer there. This is not the case for all entries; some do not have the additional space added.

Is there a particular reasoning for this? Is the '//' indicating a space for some fields but not others

Comment: and with direct entryof the same select in sql management studio, you get results or not?

Comment: Is it really a space, or a newline or some other non-printing character? Management Studio is really bad at displaying these. Try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), url)` to see the actual bytes. In any case, if the URL is not what you expect, then obviously you will get no match. `"%" + "http://mydomain" + "%"` will still not match "http://[somethingsomething]mydomain.com" -- your problem is with the column contents, not the query.